# Método con solicitud de dos parámetros c# Unity5

Tags: c#, unity, parametros

Tengo un método el cual requiere dos parámetros en c# para Unity5

```
public void BuyBullet(int Select, int Cost)
{
}
```

El método es llamado por el método OnClick de un botón el cual debe pasar estos dos parámetros , pero al intentar incrustar el método en el onClick no es posible cuando son dos parametros si cuando solo solicita un parametro.

Comment: Coloca el codigo completo, no termino de entender tu problema, pero vos podes llamar a tu metodo en cualquier event (el click es un evento) siempre y cuando vos le pases a tu metodo los parametros que requiere, no importa donde lo coloques.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, el script solo cuenta con ese método en donde solicita un selector y un costo.

Pero ir al método publico desde el onClick no es posible llamar al método cuando este solícita dos parametros

Comment: Coloca el codigo como lo estas llamado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No logre la forma de pasar dos parámetros desde el método publico, la solución fue pasar un string y este separarlo mediante **,**

```
    public void BuyBullet(string bulletCost)
    {

        //Separamos el string mediante las ,
        string[] finall = bulletCost.Split(',');

        //Asignamos el valor string pasandolo a int
        int primerParamtro = int.Parse(finall[0]);
        int segundoParametro= int.Parse(finall[1]);
}
```

De esta manera cuando tengo el objeto publico en el visual de Unity ingreso un string separando los valores por , Ej: valorUno,valorDos